# Gorutine doesn't finish executing after returning from main. Why?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to understand context in golang. I copied an example from https://golang.org/pkg/context/#example_WithCancel and changed it a bit:
Playgroud: https://play.golang.org/p/Aczc2CqcVZR

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // gen generates integers in a separate goroutine and
    // sends them to the returned channel.
    // The callers of gen need to cancel the context once
    // they are done consuming generated integers not to leak
    // the internal goroutine started by gen.
    gen := func(ctx context.Context) <-chan int {
        dst := make(chan int)
        n := 1
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    fmt.Println("DONE")
                    return // returning not to leak the goroutine
                case dst <- n:
                    n++
                }
            }
            fmt.Println("END")
        }()
        return dst
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    defer time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    defer fmt.Println("Before cancel")
    defer cancel() // cancel when we are finished consuming integers
    defer fmt.Println("After cancel")

    channel := gen(ctx)
    for n := range channel { 
        fmt.Println(n)
        if n == 5 {

            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println( <-channel)

}
```

When commenting out the

```
defer time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
```

the "DONE" never gets printed. Playgroud: (https://play.golang.org/p/K0OcyZaj_xK)

I would expect the go routine which was started in the anonymous function still to be active. Once cancel() is called due to being deferred, the select should no longer block as

```
case <-ctx.Done():
```

should be available. However it seems to just end, unless I wait for 1 second and give it time. This behavior seems very wrong.

Comment: `defer cancel()` executes cancel once func main returns i.e. after everything in func main. While `defer cancel()` is a common pattern you probably don't want to defer that much in your code.

Answer (score 2):

> This behavior seems very wrong.

It's not. That's how program execution is specified. After main and its deferred functions return, the program exits.

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution

Comment: So if I understand correctly, after returning from main all other go routines 'may' continue doing some work until all the deferred functions are done, however there is no guarantee.

Comment: Deferred functions execute before the surrounding function returns. Nothing happens after main returns.